# Largest eigenvalue of the Laplacian Matrix in an odd cycle

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-functions, graph-laplacian

**Problem:**
We have an odd cycle, $C_{2n+1}$, for $n \geq 1$, and the edges $e \in E\ $ have all one weights $w \in \{1\}^E$.

**Question:** Denote the largest eigenvalue of the Laplacian matrix of this graph as $\lambda_{\max}(L_w)$. What is the value of $\lambda_{\max}(L_w)$?

**My attempt:**

The Laplacian Matrix will look like:
$$ L_w  = \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots &\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \vdots  \end{bmatrix} $$
And I think to solve eigenvalue problem, we need to consider $det(L_w - \lambda I) =0$, take the characteristic function and then somehow we should conclude that the max value is a function of $n$ including $cos()$ operator.

I also think [cofactor expansion](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk07/07_cofactor_expansion.html) can be a potential direction. [Here](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Jones.pdf) on Chapter 3.2 there is an example, but that is on Paths and does the calculations for the adjacency matrix. I need to find the exact solution of the Laplacian form's maximum eigenvalue (because I will use it to find the result of the semidefinite program of MAX-CUT problem reduced to vertex-transitive graphs).

Comment: For a cycle graph on $n$ vertices, $L$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), so we know _all_ its [eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues). (And the proof is as easy as observing that every vector of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1 & \omega^k & \omega^{2k} & \cdots & \omega^{n - 1}\end{bmatrix}^T$, where $\omega = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)$, is an eigenvector).

Comment: For a cycle on $2n + 1$ vertices, we therefore have
$$\lambda_{\max} = \max_k (2 - \omega^k - \omega^{-k}) = \max_k 2(1 - \operatorname{Re} \omega^k) = \max_k 2\left(1 - \cos \dfrac{2k\pi i}{2n + 1} \right)$$
(in which $k$ runs from $0$ to $2n$).

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is a bit clearer. Can you also derive the largest eigenvalue? I want to tick your answer :)

Comment: I think you already editted. Thanks!!

Comment: That $i$ shouldn't be there. Anyway, I'm typing it up as a complete answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a cycle, the Laplacian matrix and the adjacency matrix as well are [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), and we know all the [eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues). If $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of the odd cycle on $2n + 1$ vertices, and $\omega = \exp \frac{2\pi i}{2n + 1}$ the $(2n + 1)$<sup>th</sup> root of unity, then every eigenvalue of $L$ is of the form
$$2 - \omega^k - \omega^{-k} = 2 - 2\operatorname{Re} \omega^k = 2 - 2 \cos \dfrac{2k\pi}{2n + 1},$$
$k = 0, \ldots, 2n$.

This is maximum when the cosine is minimum, which happens when $\dfrac{2k\pi}{2n + 1}$ is closest to $\pi$, i.e., when $k = n$ or $n + 1$ (both choices giving the same value).

Thus, the largest eigenvalue of $L$ is $$\lambda_{\max} = 2\left[1 - \cos \dfrac{2n\pi}{2n + 1} \right].$$

Comment: Can you please explain the part where you start introducing cos? Where does it come from? What is $RE \omega^k$

Comment: I think it is n-th root of unity

Comment: @independentvariable Yes, $\omega = \exp \dfrac{2\pi i}{2n + 1}$ is the $(2n + 1)$-th root of unity. So $\omega^k$ and $\omega^{-k}$ are mutually conjugate and $\omega^k + \omega^{-k}$ is twice the real part of $\omega^k$, which is $\cos \dfrac{2k\pi}{2n + 1}$.